# Jquery mobile ajax request not working after 4-5 request is made in Android

Tags: android, ajax, web-services, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an application using jQuery mobile 1.1.0 RC1 and phonegap 1.5.0

I have a single HTML page which contains all the pages in it as a div(through data-role="page")

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index Page</title>

<!-- Adding viewport -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Adding Phonegap scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
src="cordova/cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>

<!-- Adding jQuery mobile and jQuery scripts & CSS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colors.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

function page1(){
    $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {
        transition : "slide"
    });
}

function page2(){
    $.mobile.changePage("#page1", {
        transition : "slide"
    });
}
$("#page1").live("pageshow", function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        cache : false,
        url : "http://192.168.1.198:9051/something.xml"
                + "?time=" + Date.now(),
        data : {
            key : "value"
        },
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function(xml) {
            console.log("Success Page1");
        },
        error : function(xhr) {

        }
    });
});

$("#page2").live("pageshow", function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        cache : false,
        url : "http://192.168.1.198:9051/something.xml"
                + "?time=" + Date.now(),
        data : {
            key : "value"
        },
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function(xml) {
            console.log("Success Page2");
        },
        error : function(xhr) {

        }
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">Page 1</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="text" name="page1GetTime" id="page1GetTime" value="" /><a
            href="#" data-role="button" onclick="page1()" id="gotopage2"> Go to Page 2 </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">Page 2</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="text" name="page2GetTime" id="page2GetTime" value=""  /><a
            href="#" data-role="button" onclick="page2()"  id="gotopage1">Go to Page 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now when i click to "Go to page2" then page2 will be shown along with one ajax request .. If i keep on moving from one page to another then a ajax request is made.. This request stops responding after 4 to 5 request... Why is it happening?

Comment: Do you get an error or anything?  It could be that your page becomes to 'heavy'.

Comment: @shanabus No error... If it becomes heavy then how to unload stuff to make it light...How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted it out. There is a Bug in Phonegap 1.5.0. To rectify it,either we need to downgrade to phonegap 1.4.1 or upgrade to phonegap 1.6.0rc1

Answer (score 1):

If your pages become so heavy that ajax requests timeout or stop working, you may want to separate them in to different actual pages.  If they still perform poorly, you can easily force ajax off to test if that is the issue.

`data-ajax="false"`

Also, does this limitation change from one mobile device to the next or on a desktop browser?  Because your ajax becomes unresponsive at "4 or 5", it makes me think its a memory issue.

Comment: I use changePage() and Not href where i can put this data-ajax="false"..How to switch ajax off during changePage()

Comment: `changePage()` uses ajax. If you want to not use ajax and change the page programmatically, try `window.location=YOUR_URL` instead? http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mobile-changepage-and-rel-external

Answer (score 0):

Try to add data-ajax="false"  rel="external" to your links to disable ajax paging. I found it always causes issues with PhoneGap.

Comment: I use changePage() and Not href where i can put this data-ajax="false"..How to switch ajax off during changePage()

Answer (score 0):

Yes，I faced this problem too. The problem in the cordova-1.5.0.js. If included this lib, jquery ajax will fail when reenter the ajax page and use the ajax. And It is Ok in phonegap 1.4 or not include  cordova-1.5.0.js in phonegap1.5